# Sublime Text 2 - Regex Search - Non-Capture Group Syntax

Tags: regex, search, replace, sublimetext2

I'm trying to use ST2's regex capability in search & replace, but can't figure out how to probably make a non-capturing group. For this example, I want to find instances of "DEAN" which are *not* followed by "UMBER", i.e. to distinguish "DEANCARE" from "DEANUMBER"

From what I've read and used in the past, the syntax with a non-capture should be:

```
DEAN(?:UMBER)
```

Which should match "DEANCARE" but **not** "DEANUMBER". Yet instead, Sublime Text *only* finds "DEANUMBER" as if I had typed:

```
DEAN(UMBER)
```

Using square brackets on the first (or each) of the unwanted letters *does* work:

```
DEAN[^U]
```

But I'd still prefer to use the group non-match as opposed for other purposes and to avoid having to explicitly not-match each individual character. Do I have a syntax mistake, or maybe a conceptual error in how ST2's regex works?

Comment: You don't understand what a non-capturing group is. That you need is a negative lookahead: `DEAN(?!UMBER)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A non capturing group is the same as a group except it does not capture the matching portion of the regex in a back-reference.

If you were to use the regex `DEAN(?:UMBER)` on the string `DEANUMBER` then you would have a match, but referencing `\1` in, e.g. a search and replace would give you nothing, because the group is non-capturing.

Using `DEAN(UMBER)` on the other hand you could do a search and replace with `made of L\1` which would produce `made of LUMBER` because the match of the first (capturing) group is being back-referenced by `\1`. This of course is a very pointless example, if you want to learn more about groups and back-referencing I'd suggest you read [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) or some other documentation/turoial on the matter.

As suggested in the comments, what you want is a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: Hello. Sorry for opening such an old question, but i think i better write a comment to an old question instead of creating a new one. The question is like in the subject: What's the syntax of a non capturing group in Sublime Text? I use ST3, it uses Boost regex engine, i hope ST2 uses it too.

When i use your regex (DEAN(?:UMBER)) on the string DEANUMBER, it captures DEANUMBER. So how to use it properly? I need exactly what i ask about, not lookaheads/behinds.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @lucifer63: The syntax for non-capturing group is `(?:)`. In your regex however you are enclosing `DEAN(?:UMBER)` in a capturing group, that's why it captures `DEANUMBER`. The purpose of non-capturing groups is to group things together but not have them be back referenced. To illustrate the difference try the following two regexes in ST3 on the string DEANUMBER - `(DEAN)(?:UMBER)` replace with `G1: \1 - G2: \2` and `(DEAN)(UMBER)` replace with `G1: \1 - G2: \2`, that should illustrate the difference: `G1: DEAN - G2:` and `G1: DEAN - G2: UMBER` respectively.

Comment: @rvalvik: that's the reason i asked the question - for me it's G1: DEAN - G2: UMBER and G1: DEAN - G2: UMBER respectively. Look -> http://i.imgur.com/t56P2Jo.png

Comment: Your screenshot is correct, both of them match the same string. The **only** difference is that `(DEAN)(UMBER)` has `UMBER` back-referenced as `\2` whereas `(DEAN)(?:UMBER)` has no `\1` back-reference. Did you try to do a search and replace? If search and replace as I described results in `G1: DEAN - G2: UMBER` for both then something is wrong.

Comment: @rvalvik:i create a new document with only text DEANUMBER. Then i press Ctrl+Shift+F, select "Regular expression" option, I also has selected "Show context" and "Use buffer" options. Then i paste "(DEAN)(UMBER)" in the first input field ("Find"), type "lol" in "Replace field", then click "Replace" button and DEANUMBER gets replaced with lol. The same happens if i first paste "(DEAN)(?:UMBER)"

Comment: @lucifer63: As stated previously, in terms of the string they match, the two regexes are the same. They are both the same as just `DEANUMBER` the difference is what they are capturing as back-references (see http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html). If you are not using the back-referenced groups then the whole thing becomes moot and there is no difference between the two expressions, or any other permutation of groups for that matter.

Comment: Ok, but what about your words "If search and replace as I described results in G1: DEAN - G2: UMBER for both then something is wrong" ?

And what about this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group? It states clearly: non capturing expression doesn't capture the text it matches. But it does. In ST3 at least.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121255/discussion-between-rvalvik-and-lucifer63).